# Test Boolean is equal to string

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a method that turn booleans into a Yes or No text

If true return 'Yes', if false return 'No', for example:

```
export const booleanToText = function (value) {
  if (value === true) {
    return 'Yes'
  } else {
    return 'No'
  }
}
```

and I want to test this using JEST, but I think this is not the right way, what I have:

```
describe('booleanToText', () => {
  it('should be able to turn boolean true to text Yes', () => {
    const boolean = true
    const text = 'Yes'
    const booleanToText = boolean ? text : 'No'

    expect(booleanToText).toEqual('Yes')
  })
  it('should be able to turn boolean false to text No', () => {
    const boolean = false
    const text = 'No'
    const booleanToText = boolean ? text : 'Yes'

    expect(booleanToText).toEqual('No')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to first import your function.
and then use it like this `expect(booleanToText(true)).toEqual("Yes")`

so your test case would look like this:

```
 import {booleanToText} from "yourPath"
 // or if you re using just nodejs:
 // const booleanToText = require("yourPath")
 it('should be able to turn boolean true to text Yes', () => {
    const boolean = true
    const text = 'Yes'

    expect(booleanToText(boolean)).toEqual('Yes')
  })
```

Comment: Great to hear. Could you mark my answere as accepted answere please?